# Editing the tag pages and using templates

Tags: templates, tags

Pretty simple question, but probably with a complex answer. I was wondering if there is a possiblity to customize a certain tag's page.

I have a website where we I post music, and I tag the artists involved and the album ETC. I was wondering if you can customize the "tag page" to look different for an album than the default ones. Add like "info about the album" or whatever. And how I should do it, tried searching around but didnt really find anything.

Comment: [Tag Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#tag)

Comment: Figured it out [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, tag templates, and it worked out amazingly :)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates